# Evitar que se reanude la Actividad al app al rotar la pantalla

Tags: java, android, android-studio

En una app de [android](/questions/tagged/android), al rotar la pantalla del móvil, me gustaría que se siguiera ejecutando la aplicación normalmente. No obstante, al hacerlo, la actividad empieza desde el principio.

¿Cómo puedo evitarlo?

Comment: Esto ya fue preguntado, revisa en el sitio

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para evitar que la actividad se reinicie al cambiar la orientación deberás de poner en la declaración de tu Activity en el manifest la siguiente linea: `android:configChanges="orientation"` quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Para más información puedes consultar la [documentación oficial de Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: Lo he probado pero no ha funcionado

Comment: quita el keyboardHidden de la respuesta de @Joacer, déjalo como 
          <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
          
Asegúrate que lo pones en la actividad que no quieres que recargue al girar la pantalla, si no te funciona nos pones tu manifest para ver si lo estás poniendo bien